# C# Билдер, Windows Forms

Tags: c#

Задача такова:

Пункт 1: Есть программа Windows Forms в которой есть такие функции: *Желаемое имя папки*
                  *Ссылка для скачивания*
                  *Желаемое имя файла*

Пункт 2: Так же есть три переменные:

*string url
*string name
*string fname

После ввода в Пункт 1 нужных параметров в текстовом поле, они записываются в переменные пункта 2.
Задача в том, чтоб при нажатии кнопки "Билд!"
Делается программа, с определенным кодом C# который укажу Я в билдер с участием переменных в пункте 2. 
Возможно? Если да, то как? Кто сможет помочь?

Comment: У компилятора есть консольный режим. Просто, сделайте Process.Start с нужными параметрами.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe

Comment: Если нужно только выполнить код то можно использовать c# scripting  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting. Для выполнения произвольного кода внутри существующего процесса. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples